How to call a SAP Fiori app via the Launchpad?
I created a very small testapp in Visual Studio Code and I would like to call that app now from the Fiori Launchpad.
So, I created a semantic object (see picture 1) and then I created a tile via the customizing (see picture 2) and a target mapping there (see picture 3).

Picture 1

Picture 2

Picture 3


Then I created a role in the LPD_CUST:

This would be my app which I uploaded in the SE80:


But when I want to call the app I get an error:

Can somebody help me with this issue?
Did I forget something or did I do something wrong?
Thanks in advance

The eror says, that no descriptor (manifest.json) was found. Your Component.js is usually the place where the manifest should be loaded. Maybe your small test app is too small. Maybe you need to create a proper test app with a proper Component. (This is just me making assumptions).

Hello Marc, thanks for your answer. I would have a manifest.json file in the app or do I have to configurate here something what I´ve forgotten?

compare this sample Component.js with yours. Not sure where you found yours but it looks completely outdated: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw75/7.5.5/en-US/27/ce0e4987cd426f8fa3e60836316428/content.htm?no_cache=true

Hello Marc, thank you  very much. But would it be so right? If I declare the component so there:
sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'sap/ui/core/UIComponent'],
function(jQuery, UIComponent) {
"use strict";
var Component = UIComponent.extend("com.tc.stest", {
metadata : {
manifest : "json"
}
});
return Component;
});

Looks better. I think you also have to use the namespace (com.tc.stest) in your index.html line 13 and 14. See this in depth tutorial from SAP https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/fe12df2e338e43598977d09f3d191b7b

Hi Marc,
I changed it now so:  sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'sap/ui/core/UIComponent'],
function(jQuery, UIComponent) {
"use strict";
var Component = UIComponent.extend("com.tc.ztest", {
metadata : {
manifest : "json"
}
});
return Component;
});
But I still get the error
Do I have to do something in the sicf for example?

Can you open the app without using the Launchpad (SAP GUI > right click on the index.html > Test)? This requires that the SICF node /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/ztest is active. If it still doesn't work it means that your source code is the problem. If it works your tile config is the problem.
